# Using dplyr to return rows where first character in two columns match and the two rows DO NOT match

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(traffic_Count_Street = c("16th St", "17th St", 
                                        "Agnes St", "Ayers St", "Ayers St", "Ayers St", "Ayers St", "Baldwin Blvd", 
                                        "Baldwin Blvd", "Baldwin Blvd","S Brahma Blvd"), 
                     unit_Street = c("Baldwin Blvd", "Baldwin Blvd", "Baldwin Blvd", "Baldwin Blvd", "Baldwin Blvd", 
                      "Baldwin Blvd", "Baldwin Blvd", "Baldwin Blvd", "Baldwin Blvd", 
                     "Baldwin Blvd","S 14th St")), .Names = c("traffic_Count_Street", "unit_Street"
                      ), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")

   traffic_Count_Street  unit_Street
1               16th St Baldwin Blvd
2               17th St Baldwin Blvd
3              Agnes St Baldwin Blvd
4              Ayers St Baldwin Blvd
5              Ayers St Baldwin Blvd
6              Ayers St Baldwin Blvd
7              Ayers St Baldwin Blvd
8          Baldwin Blvd Baldwin Blvd
9          Baldwin Blvd Baldwin Blvd
10         Baldwin Blvd Baldwin Blvd
11        S Brahma Blvd    S 14th St
```

and I would like to return rows where either the the two columns do not match for each row OR just the first character of each column do match

The result would look like:

```
  traffic_Count_Street unit_Street
1        S Brahma Blvd   S 14th St
```

I have the following but I am not sure if its correct.

```
require(dplyr)
result = df%>% 
  filter(traffic_Count_Street != unit_Street & traffic_Count_Street[1] == unit_Street[1])
```

Comment: You will probably need to show the output you expect for the example input given here. Also, after your recent edit, the example input gives a "corrupt data frame" warning, so probably you have a mistake in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `substr` to extract the first character of each column, compare (`==`) and `filter` the rows along with the other comparison in the OP's code.

```
df %>% 
    filter(substr(traffic_Count_Street, 1, 1) == substr(unit_Street, 1, 1) & 
            traffic_Count_Street != unit_Street)
#  traffic_Count_Street unit_Street
#1        S Brahma Blvd   S 14th St
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[df[,Reduce(`!=`, .SD) & substr(.SD[[1]],1,1) == substr(.SD[[2]], 1, 1)]]
#   traffic_Count_Street unit_Street
#1:        S Brahma Blvd   S 14th St
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
subset(df, substr(traffic_Count_Street, 1, 1) == substr(unit_Street, 1, 1) &              
            traffic_Count_Street != unit_Street)
```

Comment: the final answer would be df %>% 
    filter(substr(traffic_Count_Street, 1, 1) == substr(unit_Street, 1, 1)&traffic_Count_Street != unit_Street) ?

Comment: @DataTx I was also confused by your title, description and code.  If I use that code, none of the rows in the example matches.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` fot its sugar-syntax:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[substr(traffic_Count_Street, 1, 1) == substr(unit_Street, 1, 1) & 
      traffic_Count_Street != unit_Street]

#    traffic_Count_Street unit_Street
# 1:        S Brahma Blvd   S 14th St
```